# Hypothesis testing: $1/25$ chance vs. $0.2$ claim

Tags: probability

A question from my stochastics course:

*A chocolate factory claims that since the introduction of blue as a color of M&M's, 20% of all M&M's are produced blue.*

**Question**: *Given this information, what is the probability that out of 25 randomly sampled M&M's, at most 1 is blue?*

I feel like I don't have enough information to determine this?
I have a $0.2$ probability of a blue M&M.. and now I have a $1/25$?? Can someone explain?

Comment: You don't have a 1 in 25 chance of anything. You have 25 randomly selected m+ms. What's the probability that there will be one or fewer blue? Imagine your favorite color is blue, and you open a pack of 25 m+m's and only one is blue (despite the fact that on average you'd expect five). Disappointed, you exclaim, "Only one! What were the odds of that?" Well, now you're asked to calculate it.

Comment: I see, yes. Got it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pick one M&M at random, the probability that it is not blue is $0.8$.

Hence if you take $25$ randomly (and independently) sampled M&M's, the probability that none is blue is $P(0)=0.8^{25}$.

The probability that exactly $1$ of them is blue is $P(1)=25*0.2*0.8^{24}$, because it is the probability that the first one is blue and no other, plus the probablity that the second is blue and no other, etc. until the 25th.

What you are asked for is $P(0)+P(1)$...

Answer (score 1):

There is enough information: in the sample of 25,

- there is a $\left(\frac45\right)^{25}$ chance that no M&M is blue
- there is a $25\cdot\frac15\left(\frac45\right)^{24}$ chance that a single one is

This yields the answer as the sum of these two probabilities: $0.0273897\dots$ or around 2.74%.